# How do I send and receive a request using the requests library?

Tags: python, python-requests

there is a task-from [page](http://election.task-sss.krasilnikov.spb.ru/b37d4650ab6bcd16657b72b343cb9595) get the text of all posts with more than 0 likes. As I understand it, you must first get all the tokens and IDs of possible posts from the page (which was not difficult) and make a request to the server using the requests library and these ids and get a response, since the post itself is in the code only in the form of a form without information about likes. But I don't understand much about the requests themselves and I can't figure out how to make such a request and get the html code of the post? Do I need a token? They are usually used for security and are generated by each user.

Directly [finding the assumed token and request](https://ibb.co/mBJxf9d)

[Number of likes](https://ibb.co/WKmWQ3c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you simply import the requests library and use requests.get(). More detailed response can be found here: https://realpython.com/python-requests/.